# If the denominator of a function is increasing faster than the numerator, is the overall function decreasing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So to me the answer is "yes, of course," but nobody has told me explicitly. I have learned about LIATE (log, inverse-trig, algebraic, trig, expo), so looking at a function like ${x^{70}}\over{e^x}$, can I assume that the function is decreasing? In this case the graph does appear to decrease and converge to 0.

Comment: What about something like $\frac{x}{x+\ln(x)}$

Comment: That's interesting. My guess is that since both x are increasing at the same rate, the denominator is increasing faster so the function decreases (but very slowly since it is a log).

Comment: We don't have to guess: plot @QC_QAOA's function (or write it as $\frac1{1+\frac{\ln x}x} = \frac1{1+g(x)}$ where $g$ is eventually decreasing) to see that it is eventually increasing and has limit $1$.

Comment: @JeremyKievit For positive valued functions $\,f/g\,$ has the same monotonicity as $\,\ln(f/g)$ $= \ln(f) - \ln(g)\,$, which is given by the sign of the derivative $\,f'/f - g'/g\,$ assuming the functions are differentiable. So in the end it depends on what you mean by "*increasing faster*". If it's the absolute increase rate $g' \gt f'$ then that's not enough for $f/g$ to decrease. If it's the relative increase rate $g'/g \gt f'/f$ then $f/g$ does indeed decrease.

Comment: It took me a minute to understand your logic here but I think it makes sense. What I'm understanding is that the value of $g$ plays two roles in determining the sign of the derivative. One as the numerator of $g'/g$ and the other as the denominator, meaning that the sign of the overall derivative depends on the relationship between those two. So even if $g$ is increasing for the original function, $g'/g > f'/f$ must be satisfied for the function to decrease.